# Create one large hard drive partition from multiple smaller ones

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I've got a 4TB HD that I use for cloning, moving machines etc. I previously had it setup as 1tb, 1tb, 2tb. But I was only using c. 400gb, 400gb, 500gb respectively.

I've now resized the partitions to make better use of the space but want to now make one large c 2.7tb partition out of the remaining space. But I can't seem to combine the empty spaces, is this possible?

I've attached a screenshot for reference.

[image: screenshot from disk utility]

Comment: What version of OS X (or MacOS) are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do can be done without using any third party tools. Basically you need move the last two partition to a position after the first partition. The fact that the source and destinations overlap complicates the procedure. This means you may need to move a partition twice. First to the bottom of the drive, then to a position after the first partition. For example, below is sparse bundle from which I can use to expose the necessary steps.

[image: 611]

First, I created a new partition at the end of the drive.

[image: 610]

Next, I restored the second partition source "MAX DL OLD TBC" to the forth partition destination "SL yosemite 2".

[image: 613]

Next, I removed the second partition "MAX DL OLD TBC".

[image: 614]

Next, I created a new partition about the same size as the original "MAX DL OLD TBC". The default volume label was "4 TB HD 2 1".

[image: 615]

Next, I restored the forth partition source "MAX DL OLD TBC" to the second partition destination "4 TB HD 2 1".

[image: 616]

Since there is enough free space, I created new partition after the second partition. This partition is about the same size as the "SL yosemite" partition.

[image: 617]

Next, I restored the forth partition source "SL yosemite" to the third partition destination "MAX DL OLD TBC 2 1".

[image: 618]

Finally, I removed the last two partitions.

[image: 619]

> Note: Occasionally, the Disk Utility application would become confused and not correctly display the results after executing a particular step. Therefore, I needed to quit the and relaunch the Disk Utility application between certain steps. Also, a few times I need to unmount and remount the disk image.

El Capitan users would probably be better off using the command line to create and remove the partitions. This can be done by using the command `diskutil`. Also, the `gpt` command can be useful. The Disk Utility application can still be used to copy the partitions.

Comment: I think there is a simpler solution in Disk Utility than yours: Simply create a new 400 gb volume in the 600 GB gap between 4tb and max. Restore max to it. Delete old max. Create a new 500 gb just after the "moved" max. Restore sl to the new 500 gb volume. Delete the old sl. Create a new 2.7 tb volume.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

`dd` (or asr) and CoreStorage.

Using one of the first two you have to create equally sized partitions on the disk:

- Create an exact duplicate of "MAX DL OLD TBC" (with all data!) right after  "4TB" in the 600 GB gap. Delete the old  "MAX DL OLD TBC".
- Create an exact duplicate of "SL yosemite" (with all data!) right after the "moved" "MAX DL OLD TBC". Delete the old  "SL yosemite".
- Now create a new ~2.7 TB partition in the now unfragmented unallocated disk space

You can also use CoreStorage to create a new "virtual disk" in the fragmented unallocated disk space:

- Create three new empty volumes in the three unallocated disk slices and rename them to CS1, CS2 and CS3
- Open Terminal and enter `diskutil list`

  Example:

  ```
  /dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *68.7 GB    disk1
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS 4TB                     13.9 GB    disk1s2
     3:                  Apple_HFS CS1                     6.8 GB     disk1s3
     4:                  Apple_HFS MAX DL OLD TBC          12.0 GB    disk1s4
     5:                  Apple_HFS CS2                     5.7 GB     disk1s5
     6:                  Apple_HFS SL yosemite             7.2 GB     disk1s6
     7:                  Apple_HFS CS3                     22.1 GB    disk1s7
  ```

  Your disk identifiers may be different of course.
- Create a Logical Volume Group with CS1, CS2 and CS3:

  ```
  diskutil cs create CSName disk1s3 disk1s5 disk1s7
  ```

  with the following output:

  ```
  Started CoreStorage operation
  Unmounting disk1s3
  Touching partition type on disk1s3
  Adding disk1s3 to Logical Volume Group
  Unmounting disk1s5
  Touching partition type on disk1s5
  Adding disk1s5 to Logical Volume Group
  Unmounting disk1s7
  Touching partition type on disk1s7
  Adding disk1s7 to Logical Volume Group
  Creating Core Storage Logical Volume Group
  Switching disk1s3 to Core Storage
  Switching disk1s5 to Core Storage
  Switching disk1s7 to Core Storage
  Waiting for Logical Volume Group to appear
  Discovered new Logical Volume Group "A55DDC31-D290-4A66-8D49-B83877A01001"
  Core Storage LVG UUID: A55DDC31-D290-4A66-8D49-B83877A01001
  Finished CoreStorage operation
  ```
- In the Core Storage LVG create a new Logical Volume with:

  ```
  diskutil cs createVolume lvgUUID type name size
  ```

  With the data above and one LV spanning the whole LVG that's:

  ```
  diskutil cs createVolume A55DDC31-D290-4A66-8D49-B83877A01001 jhfs+ LVName 100%
  ```

  The result of `diskutil list`is then:

  ```
  /dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *68.7 GB    disk1
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS 4TB                     13.9 GB    disk1s2
     3:          Apple_CoreStorage CSname                  6.8 GB     disk1s3
     4:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s9
     5:                  Apple_HFS MAX DL OLD TBC          12.0 GB    disk1s4
     6:          Apple_CoreStorage CSname                  5.7 GB     disk1s5
     7:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s10
     8:                  Apple_HFS SL yosemite             7.2 GB     disk1s6
     9:          Apple_CoreStorage CSname                  22.1 GB    disk1s7
    10:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s11
  /dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:                  Apple_HFS LVName                 +29.1 GB    disk2
                                   Logical Volume on disk1s3, disk1s5, ...
                                   06D80216-2EFD-43F4-A5D4-755F8D703DF1
                                   Unencrypted Fusion Drive
  ```

  The three former volumes CS1-CS3 will be "replaced" by "LVname" on your desktop.

---

The downside of the first method is the requirement to copy ~ 0.9 TB of data. The downside of the other method is the "fragmented" disk -  it's very fast though: ~60 seconds.

Comment: You know both of us assume the drive is GPT partitioned and not MBR table partitioned with a 4096 byte sector size. Also, we assume no partitions are followed by a hidden recovery partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Hmm yes, true but that's not our problem now. We rely on the given details.

Comment: I just realized you can not change the size of HFS formatted partition when the MBR table method is used. Therefore the drive is using a GPT.

Comment: A word of caution when using the `dd` command to duplicate a HFS formatted partition. This command **does** actually make an exact copy, including the UUID assigned to the partition. This presents a problem since the OS assumes no two HFS formatted partitions contain the same UUID. So, if you use the `dd` command, you will need follow with the `/System/Library/Filesystems/hfs.fs/Contents/Resources/hfs.ut‌​il -s` command to generate a new UUID. Enter the command `man hfs.util` for more info. Note: The `hfs.util` command **requires** you to omit the `/dev/` prefix when specifying the slice.